# Django NoReverseMatch error, 0 patterns tried

Tags: python, django

I've tried about a thousand different fixes suggested on different questions about this, but nothing seems to be working.

urls.py (app):

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', login_required(views.index), name='index'),
    url(r'^clock/', views.clock, name='clock'),
]
```

urls.py (project):

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from mqtt.views import auth, acl, superuser


urlpatterns = [
    url('^accounts/login/', auth_views.login,
        {'template_name': 'login.html'}
    ),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^auth$', auth),
    url(r'^superuser$', superuser),
    url(r'^acl$', acl),
    url(r'^$', include('lamp.urls')),
]
static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    lamps = request.user.lamp_set.all()
    context = {}

    if lamps:
        device_id = lamps[0].model
        context = {'device_id': device_id}

    return render(request, 'index.html', context)

def clock(request):
    return render(request, 'clock.html')
```

index.html (snippet):

```
<div class="toggle-button" id="power"></div>
<div class="toggle-button" id="alarm-clock">
<a href="{% url 'clock' %}" id='clock-link'>Clock</a>
</div>
```

When I try to load the page I get:

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'clock' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

I'm pretty new to Django, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is that an app specific `urls.py`? Are you pulling it into the projects `urls.py`?

Comment: Just added the project's one. I'm adding functionality to someone else's code so I'm not 100% confident on the mechanics of everything.

Answer (score 0):

`$` means the end of urlconf search for django. you need to remove it to enable the inner-app urls search.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('lamp.urls')), # <----
    #... rest of the urlconfs       
]
```

Comment: Tried that before I posted, and again just now. No dice.